# How to see my notification with react-native-push-notification-ios / push-notification-ios

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I'm trying to schedule my notification for now (to try if it's working)

Everything is deprecated so i use the addNotificationRequest method. I have no error and nothing happened. I have also my poermission on, on xcode i setup my app with the background mode and the notif.

Also my code on my componentdidmont on my login page :

```
componentDidMount () {
    
   const date=(new Date())
    PushNotificationIOS.addNotificationRequest(  NotificationRequest = {
     
      id:'0',
      title:'coucou',
        body:"c'est moi !",
        fireDate:date,
    }
    );
   this.RequestUserPermission();
  }
```

Did i forget something ?

Answer (score 0):

Sends notificationRequest to notification center at specified firedate. Fires immediately if firedate is not set.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.